# Странная работа select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть select с id role с 12 опциями.
Условие работает странно, если выбирается опция 10,11 или 12 то alert с Значение больше 5 не выводится, хотя первый alert(s) выводит номер опции правильно

```
$("#role").change(function() {
        var s = $("#role").val();
        alert(s);
        if (s > '5'){
          alert("Значение больше 5");
            $(".regional").addClass("hidden-lg");
            $("#regional").val(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, строка `"10"` (и `"11"`, и `"12"`) меньше, чем строка `"5"`. Сравнение происходит посимвольно. Сравнивайте числа.

```
    var s = +$("#role").val();
    alert(s);
    if (s > 5){
```